# Can I use Parse to offload my iOS notification needs?

Tags: ios, wcf, parse-platform

I have a WCF service that is running on IIS  somewhere that talks to my iPhone app. What I want to know is this: Is is possible to offload my notification requirements to Parse?

In short does Parse allow this:

- I upload my Apple certificate on Parse.com
- Parse provides me an api to which my WCF service can send requests to notify my app users.
- Parse notifies the user on my behalf.

Is this possible? I don't want to move to a dedicated host just to enable my service to able to send notifications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Note!

while parse is gone for hosting (2016),

https://www.back4app.com

is the identical code base.

---

yes that is possible, and quite easy.

It works perfectly; everything about it will make you happy.

You'll have to use some cloud code on Parse.

BTW I don't know what a WCF service is.

I urge you to ask on the parse.com QA site, and you'll probably find some specifics of how to approach the cloud code for that; just ensure it's exactly what you want before doing it.

One small point .. have you considered moving "beyond" notifications to pub nub?  Is awesome.

Google around with "using parse with pubnub"

https://help.pubnub.com/entries/22462483-How-do-I-Publish-a-Message-from-Parse-

https://parse.com/questions/combine-parse-with-pubnub-pusher-or-similar-for-real-time-messaging

See ya!

Comment: I had not heard about pubnub till you mentioned it. You learn something new everyday!

Comment: Well... PayPal killed StackMob after they acquired it.